# dynamic basename with BrowserRouter in react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

Please I have an issue building a multi-tenant SaaS solution. For every tenant, I want them to use a subdomain, so i can get the subdomain from the url, make a call to a REST api that returns data about that tenant.

For example,

1. the admin (another app entirely - admin app) creates a tenant with domain name: `tenant1`.
2. In the tenant application on my local system, I was able to go to `tenant1.localhost:3000`. I get the url, and get the domain name. I then make a call with the domain to get the theme of tenant (this is stored in localStorage).

Unfortunately, we deploy on k8 in my company and so I couldn't mimic this behavior. So i have been advised by the devOps team to use subdomain in the context, thereby having `localhost:3000/tenant1`. Remember the tenant is dynamic, so i tried this:

```
<BrowserRouter basename={"/:tenant"}>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/login" name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/set-password/:token" name="Set Password" component={SetPassword} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/" name="Default Layout" component={DefaultLayout} /> 
    </Switch>              
</BrowserRouter>
```

The solution above however makes my url to localhost:3000/:tenant/login

Please how can i use dynamic basename in the router, so it can accept:

`localhost:3000/tenant1`
`localhost:3000/tenant3`
`localhost:3000/tenant2` etc.

It can allow any, my app handles wrong domain inputted

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally used dynamic tenant with the following code

```
class App extends Component {

    state = {
        domain: ""
    }

    componentWillMount () {
        const { domain } = this.state;

        const parsedData = window.location.pathname.split("/"); 
        let domain = parsedData[1];
        this.setState({ domain: domain })
        this.props.onGetTenant(domain);                
    }

    render () {
        const { domain } = this.state;

        return () {
             <BrowserRouter basename={"/"+domain}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/login" name="Login" component={Login} />
                    <Route exact path="/set-password/:token" name="Set Password" component={SetPassword} />
                    <PrivateRoute domain={domain} path="/" name="Default Layout" component={DefaultLayout} /> 
                 </Switch>              
             </BrowserRouter> 
    }

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const { tenant} = state;
    return { tenant};
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onGetTenant: bindActionCreators( tenantActions.get, dispatch)
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Comment: what should be the "basename" in package.json for this case?

Comment: I've tried using your solution but when I login into my app the basename not changing.
could you share your PrivateRoute component?

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me using react >16 and react-router-dom v5

```
export const App = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/:tenantId?" component={LayoutRoot} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
};

export const LayoutRoot = () => {
    var { tenantId } = useParams();
     //TODO: add some validation here and inform user if tenant is invalid
    return (
        <BrowserRouter basename={tenantId}>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/login" component={LoginComponent} />
                <Route path="/dashboard" component={DashboardComponent} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
};
```

Comment: Not sure if this works with `BrowserRouter`, but with `HashRouter`, the top-level component (`LayoutRoot` in this case) fails to re-render for me on change of the base param.

Answer (score 5):

You can render updates to your router's `basename` by using the `key` property. Any changes to the key value will cause the component to re-render.

Here's a code sandbox to demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-dynamic-basename-forked-hnkk0?file=/index.js

You can hover or inspect the links in the sandbox to verify that their `href` values are correctly updating after changing the basename. You can also see that the `href`s *won't* update if you remove the `key` property from `Router`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Root = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  const basename = `basename-${count}`;

  return (
    <BrowserRouter basename={basename} key={basename}>
      <Link to="/link1">Link 1</Link>
      <br />
      <Link to="/link2">Link 2</Link>
      <br />
      Current basename: {basename}
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>change basename</button>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

render(<Root />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this also causes the everything under the browser router to re-mount, rather than just update.  Considering this is typically the top-level of the component-tree, this messes with a lot of assumptions some components may have.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a codesandbox and the utility I wrote:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-dynamic-basename-xq9tj?file=/index.js

```
import urlJoin from 'url-join';

// it's important to have an identifier in their app
export const APP_ROOT_URL = '/my-app';

export const getBaseUrlPath = () => {
  const currentPath = document.location.pathname || APP_ROOT_URL;
  const startOfAppBase = currentPath.indexOf(APP_ROOT_URL);

  let base = currentPath;

  if (startOfAppBase !== -1) {
    base = currentPath.substr(0, startOfAppBase);
  }

  base = urlJoin(base, APP_ROOT_URL);

  return base;
};
```

Comment: what should be homepage in package.json?